# 'TP_POOL support not implemented yet' error on visual studio 2013

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to setup plaso for windows but is stuck at the Libyal and Python-bindings portion, based on [this website](http://plaso.kiddaland.net/developer/building-the-tool/windows)

I'm building it on visual studio 2013. The first error is always:

```
error C1189:# error: TP_POOL support not implemented yet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to msdn for VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0tzt8e0.aspx), The error `C1189` is raised when the programmer explicitely specify the error directive. Which means there is a path leading to

```
#error TP_POOL support not implemented yet
```

The error message is explicit enough : `TP_POOL` binding is not implemented yet. You have to remove the part which try to use this feature.

The tutorial step differs with versions of Visual Studio, which means it may depend be version dependent. Try building with vs2010 if you can or use a version of the library for vs2013 if any.